# Displaying replacement character in PHP from Oracle with charset WE8MSWIN1252

Tags: php, oracle, utf-8

I'm trying to take column's content from Oracle that has the following content: `CONSULAT GÈNÈRAL DE FRANCÈ`. When i try to display it in php, i get the following: `CONSULAT G�N�RAL DE FRANC�`.

Things that i've tried:

- Setting charset for html: `<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=WE8MSWIN1252"></head>`
- Setting charset when i define PDO: `charset=WE8MSWIN1252'`
- `query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")`
- `cast(*name* AS varchar2(200)`this one works, but not the best option because i'm not sure if others columns can have same weird values so i was looking for a more global solution.

No luck so far, can somebody give me a hint please?
Thanks in advice!

Comment: Is the NLS_LANG environment variable set? It should probably be set to UTF8.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.
The NLS_LANGUAGE is set to AMERICAN.

Comment: NLS_LANG - not NLS_LANGUAGE

Comment: Check the NLS chapter of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

Comment: Thanks everyone, i'll try the Cristopher Jones suggestion.